# Plot a histogram of yearly counts

Tags: r, date, strptime

I have a csv file that consists of one column. The column presents the date of posting on a website. I want to plot a histogram to see how the number of posts varies over the years. The file contains the years (2012 to 2016) and consists of 11,000 rows.

sample of the file:

```
2     30/1/12 21:07
3      2/2/12 15:53
4       3/4/12 0:49
5     14/11/12 3:49
6     11/8/13 16:00
7      31/7/14 8:08
8     31/7/14 10:48
9       6/8/14 9:24
10    16/12/14 3:34
```

The data types is dataframe 
`class(postsData)
[1] "data.frame"`

I tried converting the data to text using `strptime` function as below:

```
formatDate <- strptime(as.character(postsData$Date),format="“%d/%m/%y")
```

then plot the histogram

```
hist(formatDate,breaks=10,xlab="year")
```

[image]

Any tip or suggestion would be useful. Thank you,

Comment: What does your desired outcome look like?  Do you need counts rather than density on the histogram?

Comment: I need the counts. My target is to produce a clear pattern of the data.

Comment: I changed the title: as others have noted, the question here isn't about parsing dates with `strptime()` (it's just fine as it was), but rather plotting a histogram with counts.

Answer (score 1):

## use lubridate::dmy_hm()

`strptime()` is overly complicated in my opinion compared to { [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) }.

```
library(lubridate)
d <- c("30/1/12 21:07",
       "2/2/12 15:53",
       "3/4/12 0:49",
       "14/11/12 3:49",
       "11/8/13 16:00",
       "31/7/14 8:08",
       "31/7/14 10:48",
       "6/8/14 9:24",
       "16/12/14 3:34")
d2 <- dmy_hm(d)
d2
```

Returns:

```
[1] "2012-01-30 21:07:00 UTC"
[2] "2012-02-02 15:53:00 UTC"
[3] "2012-04-03 00:49:00 UTC"
[4] "2012-11-14 03:49:00 UTC"
[5] "2013-08-11 16:00:00 UTC"
[6] "2014-07-31 08:08:00 UTC"
[7] "2014-07-31 10:48:00 UTC"
[8] "2014-08-06 09:24:00 UTC"
[9] "2014-12-16 03:34:00 UTC"
```

As you can see, lubridate functions return **POSIXct** objects.

```
class(d2)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Next, you can use `lubridate::year()` to get the year of each **POSIXct** object returned by `dmy_hm()`, and plot that histogram.

```
hist(year(d2))
```

Comment: is it possible to achieve the same result with strptime?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.  I think your date conversion is fine but you need to count the number of dates that occur in each year then plot that count as a histogram.

```
library(tidyverse)
# generate some data

date.seq <- tibble(xdate = seq(from = lubridate::ymd_hms('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), to=lubridate::ymd_hms('2016-12-31 24:59:59'), length.out = 100))

date.seq  %>%  
  mutate(xyear = lubridate::year(xdate)) %>% # add a column of years
  group_by(xyear) %>% 
  summarise(date_count = length(xdate)) %>%  # Count the number of dates that occur in each year
  ggplot(aes(x = xyear, y = date_count)) +
  geom_col(colour = 'black', fill = 'blue') # plot as a column graph
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with `strptime()`*, however, the `format` option is intended to specify how the is formatted.

```
df1$date <- strptime(df1$date, format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M")

# [1] "2012-01-30 21:07:00 CET"  "2012-02-02 15:53:00 CET" 
# [3] "2012-04-03 00:49:00 CEST" "2012-11-14 03:49:00 CET" 
# [5] "2013-08-11 16:00:00 CEST" "2014-07-31 08:08:00 CEST"
# [7] "2014-07-31 10:48:00 CEST" "2014-08-06 09:24:00 CEST"
# [9] "2014-12-16 03:34:00 CET"
```

What you probably want then is to use the `format()` function

```
formatDate <- format(df1$date, format="%F")
```

(or in this case simpler with `formatDate <- as.Date(df1$date)`)

and then

```
hist(formatDate, breaks=10, xlab="year")
```

---

<sup>* credits to @MikkoMarttila</sup>

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 2:10, date = c("30/1/12 21:07", "2/2/12 15:53", 
"3/4/12 0:49", "14/11/12 3:49", "11/8/13 16:00", "31/7/14 8:08", 
"31/7/14 10:48", "6/8/14 9:24", "16/12/14 3:34")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Just doing `strptime(x, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")` gives the exact same result for me.